# Ошибка 403 на backend

Tags: yii2, apache

Используется шаблон yii2-advanced. 
После переноса на продакшн (используется CentOS) на файлах скриптов и стилей ловлю ошибку 403
Т.е. страница отдается, а стили не подтягиваются. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Причем если переходить по прямой ссылке (по данным стилям), то они отдаются корректно (ответ 200).
В чем может быть причина?

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName cp.tickets.site.ru
ServerAdmin osd@site.ru
DocumentRoot "/var/www/vhost/tickets.site.ru/htdocs/backend/web"
Options FollowSymLinks
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
RewriteEngine on

<Directory "/var/www/vhost/tickets.site.ru/htdocs/backend/web">
    RewriteEngine on
    AllowOverride none
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    # otherwise forward the request to index.php
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</Directory>


ErrorLog    /var/www/vhost/tickets.site.ru/logs/cp_http_error.log
TransferLog /var/www/vhost/tickets.site.ru/logs/cp_http_access.log

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Добрый день. Проверьте права на запись в web/assets и очистите эту директорию.

Comment: права 777. Удалял.